# How to get the size of a window

Tags: wxwidgets

I want to allocate memory for the points array.

And I want to depend on screen size, so that I can draw properly.

But I don't know the size of the screen except in function `onPaint()` to call `GetClientSize()`.

And I found that the result of `GetClientSize()` and `GetSize()` is so different that I can't know what's the connection between them.

Is there anyway that I can know the size before I call draw function???

Answer (score 0):

Client size is the drawable area. Window size is , client size + title size + other frame size. all :)

Answer (score 0):

You can handle `EVT_SIZE` to be notified about size changes but usually this is not even needed: you just compare the return value of `GetClientSize()` in your `EVT_PAINT` handler with the previously cached value and update the latter if necessary.

You do need to use the client size, which is the size of the area of the window you draw on, and not the full size which also includes the menu/tool/status bars and the window decorations.